# Connect 2 objects by armature

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I have 2 meshes - a woman and hair. I need my hair to be attached to рук and in posing mode I could freely control it[image]

[image]

Comment: select the hair object, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the head bone and Ctrl P (Parent) > Bone?

Comment: what is "рук" ? make sure your particle modifier is after the armature